# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to use 'findOneAndUpdate' in mongoose and the updated JS object I am sending is not getting saved to mongo.  I do not get an error upon saving, but I do get back a null for the updated object.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?  This is example is trying to update the entire object as stored in mongo, i.e. overwrite the name object.

```
var query = {"_id": id};
var update = {name: {first: 'john', last: 'smith'}};
var options = {new: true};
People.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, person) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('got an error');
  }

  // at this point person is null.
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Turns out that the id I was searching for did not exist, hence the null return.  Works as expected!

Comment: Apparently if your document had more fields, they all get deleted. I'm sure this is something that could be avoided somehow though

Comment: @SergioMajluf You can use $set for updating only the required fields.

Comment: return inside your `if(err)` or reject if you are using promises